# Android animation stops halfway

Tags: android, animation

My problem is that, a animation that worked fine until version 4.4.4 is now sometimes cut short. Meaning in 4.4.4 it was always normaly finished however in the newer android version it happens from time to time that the animation is only half done or only starts and directly goes on to the next part in the code.

I have the following Animation (quarter_flip_flat_to_upended):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="@integer/anim_flip_half_duration"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/anim_flip_half_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="10%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/anim_flip_half_duration"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.4" />

</set>
```

I can't write the complete code but the importent parts should be the following (the class extends ViewSwitcher):

```
private Animation quarterFlipFlatToUpended; 

this.quarterFlipFlatToUpended = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.quarter_flip_flat_to_upended);

quarterFlipFlatToUpended.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {/* Empty */}
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {/* Empty */}
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                Switcher.this.startAnimation(quarterFlipUpendedToFlat);
            }
        });

this.startAnimation(quarterFlipFlatToUpended);
```